# Filter out HTTP GET request within wireshark?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to filter out HTTP GET with wireshark, but the string provided on the [official page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) isn't working at all:

```
port 80 and tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420
```

Wireshark on my system can't parse that. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki page may be outdated. Instead of the example posted there, you could just use:

> http.request.method == "GET"